# PHP Curl and json post error false

Tags: php, ajax, api, curl, post

I'm a newbie when it comes to using `PHP curl and ajax`

I've been asked to do the following (an image is attached for your consideration).. there are the requirements

[image]

initially I tried sending request with `jquery ajax` but it was not working here is the code:

```
function sendAPI(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://someurl.com/api/page/index",
    headers: {
        'x-api-key':"[API KEY GIVEN BY THE COMPANY]",
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
      id: "7001345730",
      recordNo: "1000000000",
      recordDate: "2017-12-12",
      phone: "+966555555555",
      extension: "1234",
      email: "feras@test.com",
      managerName: "Amjad",
      managerPhone: "+966555555555",
      managerMobile: "+966555555555"
    },
    success: function(data){
      console.log('lllk');
      console.log('succes: ' + data);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.log("textStatus: ", textStatus);
      console.log("errorThrown: ", errorThrown);
    }
  });
}
sendAPI();
```

I get the following error message displayed on my console

**Please note:** `I tried both json and jsonp dataType but same result`
    textStatus:  error
    errorThrown:  error

Afterwards I tried `php curl` but I am getting the error on that too.

here is php curl code:

```
$id ="7001345730";
$recordNo = "1000000000" ;
$recordIssueDate = "2017-12-12" ;
$phone = "+966555555555" ;
$extension = "1234" ;
$email = "feras@test.com" ;
$managerName = "Adeel Essa" ;
$managerPhone = "+966555555555" ;
$managerMobile = "+966555555555";

$data = array( 
  "id" => $id,
  "recordNo" =>  $recordNo,
  "recordIssueDate" =>  $recordIssueDate,
  "phone" =>  $phone,
  "extension" =>  $extension,
  "email" =>  $email,
  "managerName" =>  $managerName,
  "managerPhone" =>  $managerPhone,
  "managerMobile" =>  $managerMobile,
);


$ch = curl_init('https://someurl.com/api/page/index');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  "x-api-key: 56DAAC8KAD-SFOL9267B-B97E1A9E"
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$result = curl_exec($ch); //get return String
echo json_encode($result);


if (curl_error($ch)) {
  $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);

if (isset($error_msg)) {
    print_r($error_msg);
}
```

When I execute the above code I get the following error:

```
false
Failed to connect to wasl.elm.sa port 443: Timed out
```

---

In the end my **only question is:**

1. If I am doing right or there is something is missing in my code.
2. On both `JQuery and PHP CURL codes`.
3. If so what do I need to change.

**Requirements are also mentioned in the above image**

Please Help

Comment: İn the image it says application JSON. But you are using dataType: 'jsonp', wht says you chrome console to the ajax connection?
Are you sure that the api response with JsonP?

Comment: @MikeAron I tried both `json` and `jsonp` but same result

Comment: @amjad from image you provided it seems that someurl is domain which is not actual one. It just a dummy URL which does not exists so you are getting timeout response.

Comment: @PrathameshPalav I removed the url for a reason this is not the url where i post it is just a dummy one to hide the confidentiality coz I'm not spouses to show anything from that document thanks

Comment: is `$data` actually a JSON-encoded string? did you run it through json_encode() ? did you verify that json_encode actually returned a string, rather than bool(false) or NULL ? (which means json_encode failed for some reason)

Comment: @hanshenrik yes i just tried i still get the same error

Comment: @Amjad change the url to `http://dumpinput.ratma.net`, change the code to `$result = curl_exec($ch); var_dump($result);`, censor the sensitive information, and post the results, please

Comment: @hanshenrik here is result
`string(229) "POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: dumpinput.ratma.net
Accept: */*
x-api-key: 56DAAC8KAD-SFOL9267B-B97E1dA9E
Content-Length: 1096
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: application/json; boundary=------------------------79e86f73b88bb297`

Comment: @Amjad oh oki, there's your problem. you say you're sending a JSON-encoded string, but $data is _NOT_ a json, it's a PHP array, which makes curl send a `multipart/form-data`-encoded request. try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));`

Comment: Thank you @hanshenrik for your precious time and advise I learn alot from that.. but unfortunately, I tried again but same result, what else can I do to improve.. thank you one more time

Comment: @Amjad did you add the json_encode? run it again on `http://dumpinput.ratma.net` , what do you get?

Comment: Sorry for that late response @hanshenrik here is the response 
`string(383) "POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: dumpinput.ratma.net
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
x-api-key: http://dumpinput.ratma.net
Content-Length: 232

{"id":"7001345730","recordNo":"1000000000","recordIssueDate":"2017-12-12","phone":"+966555555555","extension":"1234","email":"feras@test.com","managerName":"Adeel Essa","managerPhone":"+966555555555","managerMobile":"+966555555555"}"
""
`

Comment: @Amjad now you're missing the "recordDate" variable, which the documentation says is mandatory. it's much closer now tho, now you're actually sending a json (you weren't earlier.)